# Max Value with Substring with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, xpath-2.0

I can't seem to get this xpath query to work with the HTMLAgilityPack with this code and I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions.

This is the query I have so far, but I can't seem to get it to return a number.

```
DocumentNode.GetAttributeValue("max(a[(@class='shackmsg')]/@href/substring-after(.,?id='))", "");
```

I'm trying to get the `MAX` value in the `href` attribute after the `=` sign on all `hrefs` with a class of ***shackmsg***.

```
How long is the beta live before it goes retail? No one knows. We do know t</span> : </a><span class="oneline_user ">legsbrogan</span>
</div>
</li>
<li id="item_31218936" class="">
<div class="oneline oneline3 op olmod_ontopic olauthor_189801">
<a class="shackmsg" rel="nofollow" href="?id=31218936" onclick="return clickItem( 31218933, 31218936);"><span class="oneline_body"><b><u><span class="jt_yellow">Current Multiplayer Servers</span>!</u></b>
<span class="jt_sample"><span class="jt_green">Nighteyes's Japan Server: </span> <span class="jt_lime">(PvE)</span>: <b>211.15.2.34</b></span>
<span class="jt_sample"><span class="jt_green">zolointo's Canada Server: </span> <span class="jt_lime">(</span></span></span> : </a><span class="oneline_user ">legsbrogan</span>
</div>
</li>
<li id="item_31218938" class="last">
<div class="oneline oneline2 op olmod_ontopic olauthor_189801">
<div class="treecollapse">
  <a class="open" rel="nofollow" href="#" onclick="toggle_collapse(31218938); return false;" title="Toggle">toggle</a>
</div>
<a class="shackmsg" rel="nofollow" href="?id=31218938" onclick="return clickItem( 31218933, 31218938);"><span class="oneline_body">Had fun freezing my ass off last night with a bunch of shackers.  Not sure who started the big tower we f...</span> : </a><span class="oneline_user ">legsbrogan</span>
</div>
<ul>
<li id="item_31218966" class="">
<div class="oneline oneline1 olmod_ontopic olauthor_128401">
<a class="shackmsg" rel="nofollow" href="?id=31218966" onclick="return clickItem( 31218933, 31218966);"><span class="oneline_body">wasn't me. I hung out on my ship for a bit listening to your kid play Christmas songs for a bit and then ...</span> : </a><span class="oneline_user ">jonin</span><a class="lightningbolt" rel=\"nofollow\" href="http://www.shacknews.com/user/jonin/posts?result_sort=postdate_asc"><img src="http://cf.shacknews.com/images/bolt.gif" alt="This person is cool!" /></a>
</div>
</li>
<li id="item_31219008" class="last">
<div class="oneline oneline0 olmod_ontopic olauthor_8618">
<a class="shackmsg" rel="nofollow" href="?id=31219008" onclick="return clickItem( 31218933, 31219008);"><span class="oneline_body">haha i heard you guys booby trapped some poor sap's space ship</span> : </a><span class="oneline_user ">Break</span><a class="lightningbolt" rel=\"nofollow\" href="http://www.shacknews.com/user/Break/posts?result_sort=postdate_asc"><img src="http://cf.shacknews.com/images/bolt.gif" alt="This person is cool!" /></a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the error/unexpected behavior you are observing?

Comment: It's returning the the "" value since it doesn't apear to find a match.

Comment: `GetAttributeValue` tries to get the value for a sinhe attribute of the selected node. have you tried `SelectSingleNode` and then getting the value?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems as far as I can see:

- You're only scanning for anchor tags in the current context. You probably want to extend to scan everywhere (use `//` in the beginning of your query):

  ```
  //a[@class='shackmsg']/@href/substring-after(., '?id=')
  ```

  *Note that I removed a pair of unnecessary parenthesis.*
- If I'm not completely mistaken, HTML Agility Pack only supports XPath 1.0 (yet I'm not totally sure). While `System.Xml.XPath` says it implements the XPath 2.0 data model, it does not actually implement XPath 2.0 (probably this is done so third party APIs can implement this API and offer XPath 2.0/XQuery support at the same time). Also have a look at [this discussion on .NET's XPath 2.0 support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.dotnet.xml/aUFPG94LtCM).

Missing XPath 2.0 support would show up as two problems:

1. Function `substring-after(...)` does not exist.

   A solution for your problem could be to use `string-lenght($string)` and `substring($string, $start, $length)` to extract the last n digits, or `translate(...)` to remove some characters:

   ```
   translate('?id=31219008', '?id=', '')
   ```

   will remove all occurences in the character class `[?id=]` (yet it is none, I just want to highlight it does not match strings, but individual characters of this set!).
2. You cannot apply functions in axis steps. This means, you cannot find the maximum value of substrings.

   Possible solution: Only fetch all substrings and find the maximum from outside XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine XPath with HTML Agility Pack and make the following code :

```
var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='shackmsg']").Select(
                   x => x.Attributes["href"].Value.Substring(4)).Max();

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

And this output :

```
31219008
```

In this code I assume to always exist the `href` attribute and always have the following structure :

```
"?id=XXXX"
```